# Windows 10 strange font in certain menus and dialog boxes

Tags: fonts, windows-10-v1607

In my Windows 10, some messages and command buttons are in a font different from the system default font after the anniversary upgrade is applied. In the screenshots below, you can see that the toolbar area has the usual system font (Segoe UI), but some of the contents, like the tabs in Notepad++, do not. Which setting should I adjust to change it back to Segoe UI?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I eventually changed the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize\GUIFont.Facename
```

to `Segoe UI`, and the key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize\GUIFont.Height
```

to `8`.