# Weird font issue on some programs on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

Some programs are displaying the wrong fonts. I think it's an issue with the Windows Fontmapper registry but can't pinpoint what caused it.
Here's an image of what it looks like,
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0bMe.png)

and what it should look like
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8AuW.png)

The font I have issue with is Simsun, but I can't delete it since it is a system protected font.
here's my font mapper registry.
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juSjU.png)

seems like I found the culprit
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN5Sj.png)
My GuiFontfacename is set to Simsun but I don't know what to change to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it now, Indeed it is an issue with my GUIfont.facename and GUIfont.height . I changed GUIfont.facename to Segoe UI and GUIfont.height to 8 and the issue is solved. Also shout out to thread which helped me solving the issue [Windows 10 strange font in certain menus and dialog boxes](https://superuser.com/questions/1128227/windows-10-strange-font-in-certain-menus-and-dialog-boxes)